# Moving view with DragGesture while having a ScrollView on top

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that can be dragged by the user. This view contains a ScrollView that shows a list of information. However, this view interferes with the DragGesture of the containing view.

The expected behavior would be that only when the user can actually scroll something, the gesture of the ScrollView would have priority over the container.

Here is the code that can be used to test the problem I'm referring to:

```swift
struct MultipleDrag: View {
    
    @GestureState private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($offset) { value, state, transaction in
                state = -value.translation.height
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { val in
                    Text(String(val))
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 200)
        .background(Color.orange)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .offset(y: -offset)
        .gesture(gesture)
    }
}
```

As you can see, by default the scrollview starts at the top. That would mean that if the user swiped down, the orange container should move downwards, even if the gesture took place in the green area (ScrollView). The same should happen when the bottom of the ScrollView was reached or when there's not enough content on the scrollview to actually scroll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this modifier:

```
.highPriorityGesture(Gesture)
```

This will make the gesture with a higher priority than other gestures.

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work. The ScrollView still takes precedence over the drag gesture.